# Bundle Morphism which is a diffeomorphism on fibres is a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $F_{1}\to E_{1}\overset{\pi_{1}}{\to}\mathcal{M}$ and $F_{2}\to E_{2}\overset{\pi_{2}}{\to}\mathcal{M}$ be two fibre bundles over the same base manifold $\mathcal{M}$. If $H:E_{1}\to E_{2}$ is a bundle morphism such that its restriction $H:E_{1p}\to E_{2p}$ to the fibres $E_{1,2p}:=\pi_{1,2}^{-1}(\{p\})$ is for all $p\in\mathcal{M}$ a diffeomorphism, I have to show that $H$ is a diffeomorphism and hence a bundle isomorphism.

But isn't that obvious? I mean $H$ is by assumption bijective, because $E_{i}$ is the disjoint union of all its fibres and $H$ is a bijective on all of them. Furthermore, $H$ is by definition smooth and since it is a diffeomomorphism for ach fibre, its inverse is smooth restricted to all fibres and hence smooth as a whole, since the total spaces are the disjoint union of all their fibres.

Comment: I don't know if it is obvious, but it is not that hard as you mentioned. A shortcut is defining $G(p,v) = (p,{H_p}^{-1}v)$, where $H_p \colon {E_1}_p \to {E_2}_p$, to show it is smooth and that $G\circ H$ an $H \circ G$ are the identity maps of $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively.

Comment: "smooth restricted to all fibres and hence smooth as a whole" is faulty. The fiber bundle is set-theoretically the disjoint union of its fibers, but *not* topologically, let alone as a smooth manifold. You also need that the map varies smoothly as you vary the fiber.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: This answer addresses the case in which $H$ is a morphism of topological fiber bundles (i.e. merely continuous). The case where $H$ is required to be smooth is different, but the counterexample shows that the argument in the question is incorrect.

As Thorgott points out in a comment, the claim is false; an extra requirement is needed so that the diffeomorphism of fibers above $p$ "varies smoothly" as we vary $p$.

As a more concrete counterexample, take the bundle $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and consider the map $\varphi(x,y)=(x,y+f(x))$. This map restricts to a diffeomorphism on each fiber (a translation), even if we chose a function $f$ which is not differentiable.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but OP requires the bundle morphism to be smooth by definition, so you have to choose $f$ differentiable in order for $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y+f(x))$ to be a bundle morphism and then the inverse is automatically smooth too.

Comment: @Thorgott right, so this is an example which elaborates on your comment: we have a map between fiber bundles which maps the fiber over $x$ into the fiber over $x$, and such that the fiberwise restriction is smooth, even though $\phi$ as a whole need not be smooth, or let alone continuous. So, this shows concretely for the OP that their reasoning for $H$ being a diffeomorphism is faulty (i.e the qn is not as trivial as it seems); they have to argue more carefully explain why $H^{-1}$ does not display such pathologies as $\phi$.

Comment: @Thorgott I interpreted "bundle morphism" as a morphism of topological fiber bundles. (incorrectly, perhaps)